# Laravel view/controller design - ajax or form submit?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is probably a general Laravel/view/controller design question and whats the best approach for my use case. Here is my use case.

Invoice Index View that has the following elements

1. Two Select Boxes

   - Customer List
   - Purchase Order List
2. A Table for Invoices
3. A Button/href to Create a New Invoice

Requirements:

- The customer list is populated with a list of customers from the backend(controller method)when I access the index view
- When the user selects a customer from the drop down, the Purchase Order List (in index view) has to be populated from the backend
- When the user selects a Purchase Order from the drop down then the Table(List) of Invoices(in index view) has to be populated (Requirement is a specific customer + purchase oder combination can have 0..N invoices)
- When the User Clicks on the Create New Invoice Button/Href(in index view)the view should be routed to a Create Invoice View(different view) that will have two text boxes(one for customer and the second for purchase order) pre-populated with the Selected Customer ID/Name, Purchase Order ID/name that was selected in the Index page/view.

Given the above, what would be the approach I should follow

1. Do I need to use AJAX and can Ajax satisfy all of the above or is this a good use case for AJAX
2. Do I need to use a Form - where I have to handle the Purchase Order change event and button click event
3. Most importantly, I would like to request for some examples to be provided on how this is done.

Appreciate the advice and help. Thanks

Comment: you can target all the clicks with simple jquery events and use ajax to update the table information from the backend, if you'd like to get a new page every single time without refreshing the page you can use a plugin called pjax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use ajax if you don't know any other javascript framework yet.Ajax will be good I think.You can use other js too. :) :)